# Google VR View attempting to load wrong file

Tags: google-vr

### tl;dr

When I attempt to initialize the `VRView.Player`, it attempts to load `<directory_of_script>/../index.html`.

### Meandering steps I've taken to get here

At first I tried to just use the example from [Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web).

```html
<!-- file path: /test3d.htm -->
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/Include/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/build/vrview.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(() => {
                var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
                    image: 'https://example.org/Images/image.jpg',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="vrview">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This resulted in an error loading the texture due to cross-domain issues.

I copied `vrview.min.js` to my `/Include/scripts/` directory and changed the script `src` parameter.

```html
<!-- file path: /test3d.htm -->
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/Include/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Include/scripts/vrview.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(() => {
                var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
                    image: '/Images/image.jpg',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="vrview">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Inexplicably, this resulted in an HTTP 404, as the iframe attempted to load `/Include/index.html`.

As a last resort, I tried to load the iframe directly.

```html
<iframe src="https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/embed?image=https://example.org/Images/image.jpg"></iframe>
```

This returned an HTTP 403 error from storage.googleapis.com:

```
AccessDeniedAccess denied.Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to object vrview/2.0/embed.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you ever find the solution?